# Simplifying a Boolean expression (confused)

Tags: boolean-algebra

Could somebody help me make sense of how to use the Boolean rules to simplify this expression?
$$(x'+(yz)')(x + z')'$$
I used distributivity to get
$$(x'+y')(x'+z')(x'+z)$$
I don't know if that was the right path to go down, or where to go from here.
Thanks.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I used distributivity to get (x' + y')(x' + z')(x' + z). I don't know if that was the right path to go down, or where to go from here.

Comment: my apologies, not awfully privy to what needs to shown when asking a question, i hope thats been alleviated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather take this from the start:
$$(x'+(yz)')(x+z')'$$
Apply De Morgan's laws to $(yz)'$ and $(x+z')'$:
$$=(x'+y'+z')zx'$$
Distribute:
$$=zx'x'+zx'y'+zxz'$$
$x'x'=x'$ and $zz'=0$:
$$=zx'+zx'y'$$
$zx'$ absorbs $zx'y'$:
$$=zx'$$
This is the simplest form.